# Is it possible to view a specific event in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, metrics

We are using Google Analytics to track when a user presses the delete button on our site. The event looks like this:

```
/*
    Category is "User_Images
    Action is delete. e.g. they clicked the delete button
    Label is "username:bob". So we know it was bob's fault
    value is 7. bob deleted 7 images
*/
_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "User_Images", "delete", "username:bob", 7]);
```

I can't figure out how to drill down to a specific event. The farthest I can go is to drill down to the summary for a specific user.

[image]

But I want to see a specific event. That is, I want to know how many images bob deleted per event. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the secondary dimension (or even primary dimension) to be any of category, action, or label, and then find your specific event. Probably should create a custom report using the c, a, and l as dimensions, and total events as the metric.

Comment: Yeah but that won't get me an individual event will it? I can get a list of dimensions, say Labels, and their metrics. But an individual event is not part of a dimension.

Comment: If you are somehow assigning a unique ID to the label, then it would be unique. But if not, then it still gives you all events in aggregate. Are you doing that for your label, assigning unique info? By the way, if you have thoughts about using a piece of personally identifiable information for your events, then don't. :) That goes against Google's ToS.